# Emmet with sublime

Tags: sublimetext3, emmet

I am trying to make something pretty easy and for some reason i can't. Generally with Emmet on html i don't have any problem, but i wanna make something custom. On javascript, when i type `log` i want on `Tab` should generate `console.log()` and write pointer inside `()`. I have searched folder with packages installed but i didn't find somewhere i could put code on. Also on the google i didn't find something that can help, i had this thing on the ATOM but i also can't find how they have it there.

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. Emmet is for HTML and CSS, not JavaScript. Please [edit] your question and **clearly** describe what exactly you're trying to do. Do you want autocompletion for JavaScript?

Comment: If emmet is not for javascript, then is there something familiar with Emmet for javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Emmet for that, just [create a snippet](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html) in Sublime Text.

Example:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[console.log($1)]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>log</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.js</scope>
</snippet>
```

If you need this to work for HTML as well, you could change the scope to `source.js,text.html`